# How to fill in rows with repeating data in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In R, when adding new data of unequal length to a data frame, the values repeat to fill the data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(first=c(1,2,3,4,5,6))
df$second <- c(1,2,3)
```

yielding:

```
  first second
1     1      1
2     2      2
3     3      3
4     4      1
5     5      2
6     6      3
```

However, pandas requires equal index lengths.

How do I "fill in" repeating data in pandas like I can in R?

Comment: If `len(df)` is not a perfect multiple of the list length, take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47185435/4909087).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems there is no elegant way. This is the workaround I just figured out. Basically create a repeating list just bigger than original dataframe, and then left join them.

```
import pandas
df = pandas.DataFrame(range(100), columns=['first'])
repeat_arr = [1, 2, 3]
df = df.join(pandas.DataFrame(repeat_arr * (len(df)/len(repeat_arr)+1),
    columns=['second']))
```

Answer (score 14):

The cycle method from itertools is good for repeating a common pattern.

```
from itertools import cycle

seq = cycle([1, 2, 3])
df['Seq'] = [next(seq) for count in range(df.shape[0])]
```

Comment: I personally think this is the best solution.

Answer (score 3):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def put(df, column, values):
    df[column] = 0
    np.put(df[column], np.arange(len(df)), values)

df = pd.DataFrame({'first':range(1, 8)})    
put(df, 'second', [1,2,3])
```

yields

```
   first  second
0      1       1
1      2       2
2      3       3
3      4       1
4      5       2
5      6       3
6      7       1
```

Not particularly beautiful, but one "feature" it possesses is that you do not have to worry if the length of the DataFrame is a multiple of the length of the repeated values. `np.put` repeats the values as necessary.

---

My first answer was:

```
import itertools as IT
df['second'] = list(IT.islice(IT.cycle([1,2,3]), len(df)))
```

but it turns out this is significantly slower:

```
In [312]: df = pd.DataFrame({'first':range(10**6)})

In [313]: %timeit df['second'] = list(IT.islice(IT.cycle([1,2,3]), len(df)))
10 loops, best of 3: 143 ms per loop

In [316]: %timeit df['second'] = 0; np.put(df['second'], np.arange(N), [1,2,3])
10 loops, best of 3: 27.9 ms per loop
```

Comment: This is nice -- though in my particular case, I don't want to have the numbers fill in if they don't "fit" the length, but +1 for more general utility.

Answer (score 2):

How general of a solution are you looking for? I tried to make this a little less hard-coded:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas 

df = pandas.DataFrame(np.arange(1,7), columns=['first'])

base = [1, 2, 3]
df['second'] = base * (df.shape[0]/len(base))
print(df.to_string())


   first  second
0      1       1
1      2       2
2      3       3
3      4       1
4      5       2
5      6       3
```

Comment: Note that the 2nd column assignment has only 3 (not 6) values.

Comment: The "repeating data" is not duplicate columns.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I needed to repeat the values without knowing the length of the sub-list, i.e. checking the length of every group.
This was my solution:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas 

df = pandas.DataFrame(['a','a','a','b','b','b','b'], columns=['first'])

list = df.groupby('first').apply(lambda x: range(len(x))).tolist()
loop = [val for sublist in list for val in sublist]
df['second']=loop

df
  first  second
0     a       0
1     a       1
2     a       2
3     b       0
4     b       1
5     b       2
6     b       3
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably inefficient, but here's sort of a pure pandas solution.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

base = [1,2,3]
df = pd.DataFrame(data = None,index = np.arange(10),columns = ["filler"])
df["filler"][:len(base)] = base

df["tmp"] = np.arange(len(df)) % len(base)
df["filler"] = df.sort_values("tmp")["filler"].ffill() #.sort_index()
print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try using the power of modulo (%). You can take the value (or index) of first and use the length of second as the modulus to get the value (or index) you're looking for. Something like:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame([0,1,2,3,4,5], columns=['first'])
sec = [0,1,2]
df['second'] = df['first'].apply(lambda x: x % len(sec) )
print(df)
   first  second
0      0       0
1      1       1
2      2       2
3      3       0
4      4       1
5      5       2
```

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`numpy.tile`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) to repeat an array by a number of times.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

first = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
second = [1, 2, 3]

df = pd.DataFrame({"first": first, "second": np.tile(second, 2)})

print(df)
   first  second
0      1       1
1      2       2
2      3       3
3      4       1
4      5       2
5      6       3
```