# Assign column of repeating values from a list

Tags: python, pandas, list, repeat

Suppose I have a list of data. For `eg [1,2,3,4,5]` and I have `1704` rows in my DataFrame. Now I want to add new column with this values only but it should be repeated till the last row as shown below:

```
1  
2  
3  
4  
5  
1  
2  
3  
4  
5  
..
```

and so on till the last record. I tried `df['New Column']=pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5])` but it inserts record only in first 5 rows but I want this series to be repeated till the last. I referred many posts on SO but didn't found any relevant post. I am a newbie to pandas framework. Please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Below, I propose two solutions that also handle situations where the length of `df` is not a perfect multiple of the list length.

#### [`np.tile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html)

```
v = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
df['NewCol'] = np.tile(v, len(df) // len(v) + 1)[:len(df)]
```

---

#### `cycle` and `islice`

A pure-python approach featuring `itertools`.

```
from itertools import cycle, islice

it = cycle([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
df['NewCol'] = list(islice(it, len(df)))
```

Comment: @EdChum Thank you. Let me know if you find a suitable dupe... will remove.

Comment: Yeah it worked. Thanks @COLDSPEED but can you elaborate your code. Little bit difficult to understand

Comment: @SiddheshKalgaonkar `np.tile` just repeats the same thing `n` times. `np.tile([1, 2, 3], 2)` becomes `[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]`. I repeat as many times as needed and then do a slice at the end to get rid of excess elements.

Comment: yeah i got slice part but what does len(df) // len(v) + 1 this code means ? Is it a division or something else. So it will divide 1704/5 then add 1 ?

Comment: @SiddheshKalgaonkar Simple math. If I want to repeat 5 numbers to 48, I'll repeat it to 50 and take the first 48 values.

Answer (score 2):

Or you can just do within basic calculation.

```
df['New']=(df.index%5).values
df.New=df.New.add(1)
```

Comment: @SiddheshKalgaonkar `df.index%5` get the residual which will return 0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4, then assign the value add one , will be your output

Comment: Nice :) Thank you @Wen

Comment: @SiddheshKalgaonkar YW~ since Cold's method is more flexible :-)